# .htaccess code not working and showing 404 while making pretty URL's

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to make pretty URL with more than one parameter but it seems that i am not able to achieve it by the `.htaccess` code i am using. Following is my `.htaccess` code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4 [L,QSA]
```

I am making the URL such that it can only access parameters from alphabets and numbers only & also some special symbols.

This is PHP code i am using:

```
if(!empty($_GET))
        {
            $myFile = "log.txt";
            $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

            $data['logTime']  = date('d M Y h:i:s A');
            $data['param1']   = $_GET['param1'];
            $data['param2']   = $_GET['param2'];
            $data['param3']   = $_GET['param3'];
            $data['param4']   = $_GET['param4'];

            $status = fwrite($fh, json_encode($data)."\n");
            fclose($fh);

            if($status > 0)
                {
                    deliver_response(200, "success", "Request Successful!");
                }

            else
                {
                    deliver_response(400, "failed", "Invalid Request!");
                }

        }
```

Where is the code failure i am facing?

I want to make the request such that even if the URL parameters are not passed then the default values should be passed in those variables so that it can execute the else block

Comment: `.htaccess` doesn't contain "code". And how is your rewrite rule related to the input paths? What are the input URLs? Where's the access and rewrite log? Are you alluding to the placeholders being optional?

Comment: i am using only rewrite rules. Parameter is like `www.test.com/api/index.php?param1=value&param2=value&param3=value&param4=value`

Answer (score 0):

your code work, i think, i just tested on my server , and in log file is txt:

```
{"logTime":"18 Mar 2018 03:52:58 PM","param1":"value","param2":"value","param3":"value","param4":"value"}
```

as in your answer to mario you use url as:

```
www.test.com/api/index.php?param1=value&param2=value&param3=value&param4=value
```

try to use without subfolder **/api/**index.php or add this folder to your .htaccess file

Comment: means i didn't get you exactly where should i modify?

Comment: I also have one problem that if i do not pass parameter to any of the variable then it gives an error of 404 why so shouldn't it just display blank value for that?

Answer (score 0):

To fix error with params you can use if else as:

```
    if(!empty($_GET['param1'])) {
       $data['param1']   = $_GET['param1'];
     } else {
        $data['param1'] = "nothing1";
     }

   if(!empty($_GET['param2'])) {
       $data['param2']   = $_GET['param2'];
     } else {
        $data['param2'] = "nothing2";
     }

   if(!empty($_GET['param3'])) {
       $data['param3']   = $_GET['param3'];
     } else {
        $data['param3'] = "nothing3";
     }

   if(!empty($_GET['param4'])) {
       $data['param4']   = $_GET['param4'];
     } else {
        $data['param4'] = "nothing4";
     }
```

in your .htaccess file add folder api as

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/api/?$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4 [L,QSA]
```

of course you also need to move index.php and your log.txt file to this folder.